# whats wrong with my menu that is having an issue with propagation and dont let me redirect?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue when I try to open my dropdown menu it works well , but when I try to click one sub menu to be redirected then close the dropdown , and it also if I trigger the event too many times it never ends propagation. this is what my code looks like.

sidebar

```
<nav class="side-navbar">
   <div class="sidebar-header d-flex align-items-center">
   <div class="avatar"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/avatar-1.jpg'); ?>" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
      <div class="title">
         <h1 class="h4">Mark Stephen</h1>
         <p>Web Designer</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <span class="heading">Main</span>
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="active"> <a href="./"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
      <?php foreach ($fields as $section): ?>
         <li class="site-menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse">
               <img src="<?= $section['icon']?>" alt="" class="menu-icon"> <span><?= $section['section'] ?></span>
               <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse site-menu-sub">
              <?php foreach ($section['data'] as $submenu): ?>
                  <li>
                      <a href="<?= $submenu['url']?>">
                          <?= $submenu['value'] ?>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jquery

```
$('.list-unstyled li:has(ul)').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
        }else{
            $('.list-unstyled li ul').slideUp();
            $('.list-unstyled li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you positive that the `:has` pseudo-class works as expected? According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) it's browser support is zero at the moment.

Comment: add a working demo